# How to recreate this complex iteration

Tags: plotting, complex, iteration

I came across this image in a book Im reading:

[image]

(taken from Rational Iteration Complex Analytic Dynamical Systems from Steinmetz. I hope it is okay to share it here)

and I try to recreate it in Mathematica. I tried

`JuliaSetPlot[(9 + 2 z + 9 z^2)/20, z]`

which gives a complete different picture.

[image]

I also tried to use

`ColorFunction ->  With[{cf = ColorData["M10DefaultFractalGradient"]}, cf@Sqrt[#3] &]`

which doesn't improve anything. So `JuliaSetPlot` might not be the right method. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 13):

The theorem is talking about disks and you've plotted a Julia set which doesn't involve transforming any disks, but instead iterates at every point and testing if that point reaches the escape radius. I might not be reading it correctly, but it looks like the image is an iterated conformal map of some initial configuration of disks that touch the unit circle at a point.

This is a bit of a rough answer that cheats a bit by converting to an image and uses WFR function [`"ComplexTransformImage"`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ComplexTransformImage/) to do the heavy lifting. Hopefully somebody can improve upon it, but it looks a bit more like your picture at least:

```
(* Start by generating the disks and creating an image *)
SeedRandom[1];
img = Rasterize[Graphics[
   Table[{RandomColor[], Disk[{u, 0}, 1 - u]}, {u, 0, 1, .025}]
   , ImagePadding -> 50], RasterSize -> 1024]

(* Apply the conformal map to the image *)
f[{x_, y_}] := With[{z = x + y I}, (9 + 2 z + 9 z^2)/20]
ResourceFunction["ComplexTransformImage"][img, f, 0.8, 1]
```

[image: disks and warped disks]

The left image is the initial configuration of disks, and the right is what you get after applying the map once with a range setting of 0.8.